ffmpeg fails to start
Whenever I try to start ffmpeg I get

The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005)

And programs don't detect it's existence despite being in system path.
please help i am an idiot

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you're trying to use ffmpeg 7.0.1, then according to this videohelp.com forum thread, you would need to use ffmpeg-release-essentials 7.0.1 because the full version links to a Windows 10 dll. Or you could use 7.0.

will check that

as andrew morton said, using the full version requires windows 10 due to the DLLs required.
after waiting for a download slower than archive.org speeds, i can confirm using the essential version fixes the problem

Download is here: https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/
